# Changing the default TIFF viewer in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, activex

I have installed the AlternaTIFF viewer in IE (both 6 and 7, on separate computers), but based on the results of the [test page](http://www.alternatiff.com/testpage.html), it is not being recognized as the default TIFF viewer inside Internet Explorer. It is installed and functioning, just not used by default.

Is there any way to force IE to use AlternaTIFF as the default plugin to render TIFF files?

Comment: If anyone comes up with a better suggestion, I'd be more than happy to accept their answer instead of my own hack job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to overwrite the default viewer is to uninstall and reinstall the application/plugin that you would like to use as the default viewer, which will overwrite the bindings or associations of the previous default plugin.